# CV Calender not showing current and next month when we load it first time

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have integrated CV Calender library in my project. The implementation has been done correctly but it is not showing me the current month and the next month, here is the image link. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjWmV.png

It should load the current month but it is not which is October. Also, when I click next, it is not loading next month but December month is loaded correctly :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnxEV.png

What might be the problem?

Comment: Any code you can share, perhaps?

Comment: @ Jacob Ahlberg its an existing project so implementation is and other functionalities are there